# Loading a large and dynamically changing data set into a table

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a large set of data that occasionally might be updated in the background. As a self teaching experiment I do not wish to rely on any framework. Right now I am trying to find the right place with the MVC/MVVC patterns within a DDD/CQRS context.

In order to populate a table I do a query of a large data set and limit the results to twice the number of displayed rows. Once the user scrolls past half of the query, I query for the next batch of results.

I am loading all results into an array as the user scrolls, just a progressive load without throwing away non displayed rows.

**Who is responsible for building the array of results converted to domain objects? The model of the MVC or the data repository?**

Ideally I would like to reuse my MVC model without being always concerned about limiting the query results.

If data is updated in the background, a system event is created. However in the cases where a new row was created, I want my application to animate the background insertion of a new row, not just discard the query and reload the table. In such case I guess that a background process must load a copy of the current query and compare it with the existing one. It should create a "New Rows System Event" with the positions of the new rows.

**Which component should compare current query results with previous ones in order to calculate insertion and deletion points? A system service? The MVC model?**

My final concern is that loading a set of rows with multiple limited queries, might be inconsistent if the data is updated in the background. How/Where should I enforce this consistency?

Comment: The data displayed are always stale in some extent. Why not just let the user refresh or make the system do it periodically.

Comment: Considering a CQRS architecture, if a user request a new row, the command and the query are asynchronous events. I think that in such case, if you want to render as soon as possible the new empty row, it can only be the system and not the user, who decides when to reload a query based on when the database is updated, not when the user clicks the button for a new row.

Comment: I think the client is responsible for detect the data change(by scanning periodically), otherwise the server needs to broadcast a dataUpdatedEvent(which I think a waste of network) or keep a client memo to decide which client is interested in the update(which I think adds a lot of complexity). Hmm...How is the comment notification feature implemented on StackOverflow?

Comment: For me when to update a query is irrelevant. I already have an Event object when the database is updated.  My question is about (1) in which patterns/components I should build up partial query results and (2) compare differences from previous queries to animate insertions or deletions.

Comment: Take a look at SignalR so you can push data to the client when it changes.

Comment: I already have data pushed to my client. I just need to know which DDD layer (application? domain?) and pattern/component (model? service? repository?) should hold my results and calculate insertion points. A quick lick to SignalR does not seem to show a domain driven architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQRS and DDD = one Domain model and at least one Query model. Now, it's for your own good to not think of DDD as of something with many rules which broken will make you the DDD public enemy no1.

Let's think a bit: Once a Domain object is updated and a domain event is published, you'll have an event handler which will update the query model. Which query model is exactly the one you need for the UI (the view models).

The client UI should request updates (passing the current model datetime stamp) at an interval. Which updates are also part of the query model. In order to detect what changed, the update should have a datetime stamp which will get compared with the one currently shown. If it's a web app, then I strongly suggest to use a js framework like angularjs.org

Now, The MVC Model in this scenario is the query repository. When insert/edit a row, the Model will be a service (or a command handler) which will update the Domain. Everything related to Domain changes and query model generation is outside the UI, as a part of a Services/Application (call it whatever you wish) layer.

Comment: Nice! So in MVC the model should be a service between the Application and Domain layer, right? I use NoSQL database which sends me a message whenever a mapreduce function is triggered, therefore I do not need to request updates. Whenever my repos return a sequence of root objects, I return a custom Array class that provides me with some lazy loading. I am thinking now about expanding that class with a timestamp, maybe even an UID set during creation inside my repo...but that does not look like something I have seen before. Would that be too crazy? Then repos should manage the age of queries :/

Comment: The MVC model represetns the bits of other layers usable by the UI. MVC exists ONLY inside the UI. The UI should ask for updates, regardless of the db used. Also, the concept of lazy loading (LL) has no place here or in the Repository pattern. LL is an ORM workaround, leave it there. The query repo should return whatever the UI needs as a DTO. The updating of query model is done outside UI or db. The db just persists the changes, but another component manages the process. Once again, don't worry much about how the layer is called. I prefer to call it Services, but that's my opinion only

Comment: Thanks! I realized after my comment that my CustomArray should not have UID or timestamp, since that is needed only for certain models. However you make me think about "query repo returning whatever the UI needs as a DTO". Before CQRS my repos returned root entities only (List<Entity>), but since the Query part of CQRS can be separated from the entities of the domain, I added List<DTO>. Oh well, that is a whole different question and I must review my knowledge about CQRS

Comment: OMG! I've just realized on my own code that in the past, I used my CustomArray<Entity> to simulate LL outise a repo for large query results by caching internally calls to a Repo.FindByID(). Now with your answer I will get some neurons working, but I will have to evaluate the tricks of having a "revision" of the DTO on screen/Application Layer different to the "revision" of the Entity on Domain Layer, thanks @MikeSW